# Regex issue in Grunt string replace

Tags: regex, gruntjs

Somehow this is not replacing my text. Here is the code:

```
pattern: '<meta name="description" content="/(.*)/i" />',
replacement: '<meta name="description" content="<%= clientAppMetaDataDescription %>" />'
```

If I write down description content manually, it is replaced with variable content.

Comment: What are you using `grunt-string-replace`, `grunt-regex-replace` or something else?

Comment: grunt-string-replace

Comment: I'm guessing `clientAppMetaDataDescription` is not defined, you could try using `replacement: function (match, p1) { return /* whatever  value */; }` you could also add some debugging to the function to check the value.

Comment: As for the regex, the `i` modifier is useless as there are no symbols that have different cases in the pattern. Moreover, using a pattern that may match an empty string in a replace function is fraught with unwanted side effects. So,  try `.+` (or `/.+/` if regex delimiters are required).